# Resolving TCDL tags from dynamic component presentations

Tags: 2013, broker, componentpresentation, dynamic-publishing

I have the following setup:

Two component templates: CT Commercial, CT Commercial block, both dynamic and set to REL. 
Commercial is a simple component with title and text. Commercial block has a block title and link to one or more commercial component.

**CT Commercial:**

```
<h3>@@Component.Fields.title@@</h3>
<p>@@Component.Fields.text@@</p>
```

**CT Commercial Block:**

```
<h1>@@Component.Fields.commercialtitle@@</h1>
   <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="commerciallist" -->
      @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field, "tcm:32-17299-32")@@ 
   <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

I have Component Commercial_1 with title="Title 1" and text="Text 1"

I have Component Commercial_Block_1 with title="Commercial block 1 title" and commerciallist="tcm:32-17297" // link to Commercial_1 component

When I publish Commercial_1 to broker DB in the COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS table I have

```
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<p>Text 1</p>
```

When I publish Commercial_Block_1 to broker DB in the COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS table I have

```
<h1>Commercial block 1 title</h1>
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:32-17297" templateURI="tcm:32-17299-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"><h3>Title 1</h3>
<p>Text 1</p></tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
```

Component Commercial_Block_1 is added to a page as Component presentation and page is published. Page output is:

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:32-17305-64" ComponentURI="tcm:32-19345" TemplateURI="tcm:32-19335-32"/>
```

This returns Commercial_Block_1 with appropriate CT from the broker DB and my page has following html:

```
<h1>Commercial block 1 title</h1>
<h3>Title 1</h3>
<p>Text 1</p>
```

Everything fine so far.

Now, I would like to change Commercial_1 title to "Changed Title 1" and republish Commercial_1 as dynamic component.

I was hoping that this would produce a change on my page, but it does not. 
It seems that when

```
<h1>Commercial block 1 title</h1>
    <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:32-17297" templateURI="tcm:32-17299-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"><h3>Title 1</h3>
    <p>Text 1</p></tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
```

is retrieved form the DB I get the Embedded content from inside the component presentation tag instead of content from that component presentation.

Is this behavior by design, or am I doing something wrong?

**Note:**
When I replace

```
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" componentURI="tcm:32-17297" templateURI="tcm:32-17299-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL"><h3>Title 1</h3>
<p>Text 1</p></tcdl:ComponentPresentation>
```

with

```
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" ComponentURI="tcm:32-17297"  TemplateURI="tcm:32-17299-32"/>
```

in the broker DB , everything is working as expected (republishing Commercial_1 component is producing visible change on my page ).

If this is caused by Embedded vs Dynamic type, how can I change output of RenderComponentPresentation to create type Dynamic instead of Embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue before, I managed it in the same way you did, I just added `<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" />`, I think you can continue doing it. What I did is to add a .NET TBB at the end in order to keep it as Embedded when it is in preview mode and Dynamic with it is in Publishing mode

**UPDATE**
Checking a little bit the source code for the Render Engine, it seems that `@@RenderComponentPresentation@@` will produce `<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" />` if the Context item is a Page if not it will always produce `<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Embedded" />`

Comment: Hi Eric, indeed, RCP is producing dynamic on the PT level and Embedded on the CT level. If this is by design then I see no other solution then to go with your suggestion to change Embedded to Dynamic in the Output package item. Tnx

Answer (score 3):

A hotfix is now available from Support for this setup, CM_2013.1.1.1832.zip
for rendering in the context of a dynamic component presentation (without a page).